# Programmatically sending "net send"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to figure out how to write a method to not use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class but still send messages to other computers as if it's from `net.exe`, even though it isn't.

If it matters, I'm writing an all-in-one framework for my workplace and combining key features we use into one framework/.dll is a huge plus.

Comment: Note to newbie: your not supposed to sign your posts ("-Zack").  The "thanks" is ok, though some frown on that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the win32 api [NetMessageBufferSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370605(VS.85).aspx) for this.

You can use [P/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetMessageBufferSend.html) to call it from C#.

**Note** that msdn states:

> [This function is not supported as of Windows Vista because the messenger service is not supported.]

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this for now until I research steamer's suggestion more.

Comment: The messenger service has been disabled since WinXP Service Pack 2 because of spammers abusing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Messenger Service API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630960(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I'll investigate this at a later time. I'll try fretje's idea first then look into using that API